# Can't define one QUAD properly

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I'm want to have a rectangular cube. One wall has face on the wrong side so I can't see pink colour. This is good side of the cube:

[image: good side]

At the back of the cube there is grey back face of the wall: 
[image: bad side]

This is the code:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    //floor
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, floor_diffuse);
    glVertex3f(-floor_size_x / 2, 0, floor_size_z / 2);
    glVertex3f(floor_size_x / 2, 0, floor_size_z / 2);
    glVertex3f(floor_size_x / 2, 0, -floor_size_z / 2);
    glVertex3f(-floor_size_x / 2, 0, -floor_size_z / 2);

    //roof
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, roof_diffuse);
    glVertex3f(-floor_size_x / 2, wall_height, floor_size_z / 2);
    glVertex3f(floor_size_x / 2, wall_height, floor_size_z / 2);
    glVertex3f(floor_size_x / 2, wall_height, -floor_size_z / 2);
    glVertex3f(-floor_size_x / 2, wall_height, -floor_size_z / 2);      
    //walls
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, walls_diffuse);
    glVertex3f(-floor_size_x / 2, 0, floor_size_z / 2);
    glVertex3f(-floor_size_x / 2, wall_height, floor_size_z / 2);
    glVertex3f(-floor_size_x / 2, wall_height, -floor_size_z / 2);
    glVertex3f(-floor_size_x / 2, 0, -floor_size_z / 2);

    glVertex3f(floor_size_x / 2, 0, floor_size_z / 2);
    glVertex3f(floor_size_x / 2, wall_height, floor_size_z / 2);
    glVertex3f(floor_size_x / 2, wall_height, -floor_size_z / 2);
    glVertex3f(floor_size_x / 2, 0, -floor_size_z / 2);

    glVertex3f(-floor_size_x / 2, 0, -floor_size_z / 2);
    glVertex3f(-floor_size_x / 2, wall_height, -floor_size_z / 2);
    glVertex3f(floor_size_x / 2, wall_height, -floor_size_z / 2);
    glVertex3f(floor_size_x / 2, 0, -floor_size_z / 2);     

    //BAD WALL
    glVertex3f(floor_size_x / 2, 0, floor_size_z / 2);
    glVertex3f(floor_size_x / 2, wall_height, floor_size_z / 2);
    glVertex3f(-floor_size_x / 2, wall_height, floor_size_z / 2);
    glVertex3f(-floor_size_x / 2, 0, floor_size_z / 2);

    glEnd();
```

I've tried all combinations (counter)clockwise order but result is still the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it really gray or is it just too far from the light?

Comment: Did you set vertex color correctly? The good walls, floor, and ceiling all fade to black on the bad end...

Comment: Light is in the centre of the cube. This grey wall is pink on the other side.

Comment: Can you describe how the images are oriented in your coordinate system? The one facing the bad wall, where's +X and where's +Z?

Comment: I made pictures with coordinate system.

Comment: I made a temporary solution. Now every face has fixed normal vector. Cube is even now more pleasant to watch. Normal vectors were broken but I don't know why.

Comment: You didn't set normal vectors at all, so I think that OpenGL used the default one - one of your walls was fully lit, one was dark and all the others were interpolated between light and dark.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're identifying your walls incorrectly. The ones you create as 1st (`X = - floor_size_x / 2`), 3rd (`Z = - floor_size_z / 2`) and 4th (`Z = floor_size_z / 2`) are all specified clockwise, while the 2nd one (`X = floor_size_x / 2`) is specified counter-clockwise. I'd guess this is actually the incorrect one.

Comment: I changed order of second wall and... nothing happen. Problem is with 4th wall because when I remove it there is black hole instead of grey.

Comment: @Linkas If you've tried the 4th wall in both clockwise and counter-clockwise order and it's the same, it's *really* weird. Does anything happen when you change its colour (just for the 4th wall)?

Comment: When I change the colour of the 4th wall there is a change but on the other side. It is weird because always one side of the cube is darker (when I remove all walls I can see it on the roof and floor) though changing light position.